# How to send large json data inside the body of http post

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I need to send a large object with my post method. but it kept giving me error.

```
Future getResults() async {
    var res = await http.post('$SERVER_IP/api/anything/search',
    headers: {'Authorization': token, "Accept": "application/json"}, 
    body: {
      "name": "",
      "type": "",
      "organization": "",
      "state": "CA",
      "appliesTo": {
        "Camp": "true",
        "Fees": "false",
        "Lessons": "false",
      },
    }).catchError((e) => print({"error": e}));
    return json.decode(res.body);
  }
```

I realized that body only accept Map<String, String>. So I added json.encode to my "appliesTo" object.

```
Future getResults() async {
    var res = await http.post('$SERVER_IP/api/anything/search',
    headers: {'Authorization': token, "Accept": "application/json"}, 
    body: {
      "name": "",
      "type": "",
      "organization": "",
      "state": "CA",
      "appliesTo": json.encode({
        "Camp": "true",
        "Fees": "false",
        "Lessons": "false",
      }),
    }).catchError((e) => print({"error": e}));
    return json.decode(res.body);
  }
```

After that it worked and I got a returned data. But my server was ignoring whole "appliesTo" object. So I didn't get the expected data. it's not a problem in my server. I tested it with postman. this flutter http post is not sending proper json body.
So my question is how to attatch large object to the body? was using json.encode at the middle of the object wrong? what is the proper way of doing it? can anyone help?
PS: I wraped the whole Map with json.encode and it gave me error

Comment: Would help if you showed the errors.

Comment: you mean when the app stop? it's something like "Map<String, Dynamic> not acceptable in Map<String, String>. it's when I didn't use the json.encode. but now I'm getting data. but my backend is ignoring what's inside json.encode. So, I'm getting a different result.

Comment: so, what I really want to know is how to add this kind of big object at http.post? was using json.encode at the middle the wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/0.12.2/http/post.html) of the `http` package states that

> If `body` is a `Map`, it's encoded as form fields using `encoding`. The content-type of the request will be set to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`; this cannot be overridden.

If you want to send JSON data instead, you have to encode the `body` manually. Since the content type defaults to `text/plain` if `body` is a `String`, you also have to set the `Content-Type` header explicitly.

```dart
http.post('$SERVER_IP/api/anything/search',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': token, 
      "Accept": "application/json", 
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }, 
    body: json.encode({
      "name": "",
      "type": "",
      "organization": "",
      "state": "CA",
      "appliesTo": {
        "Camp": "true",
        "Fees": "false",
        "Lessons": "false",
      },
    }))
```

Comment: "Content-Type": "application/json" is the solution, Since it's default was text/plain